# Assets.xcassets disappears in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcasset

I have a projects that had many many assets that took countless hours to design. One day I went onto my project and my whole assets.xcassets folder is empty. The title is colored red and when I click on it it is just an empty file, no information in it. There is also no file for it in the file view of my project. How do I get it back. It is not in the trash can. It was emptied recently and it may have permanently removed my file. I have not done anything with source control. I never knew what it was. Now I need my assets because most of them were not saved anywhere else. I have also tried using  EaseUS Data Recovery to recover it but it did not find the file. What can I do to get it back?

Comment: Do you have any kind of backup?

Comment: I was supposed to have a backup, but when I went to access it I got an error that it was unable to save backups, and I never got that when it was supposed to be backing up. Is there any way to get the file back now without a backup?

Comment: Do you have timemachine enabled?, not a succesfull backup, but just having it enabled.

Comment: The error was with time machine, it never saved the backup because of an error and never told me so I though it did.

Comment: Timemachine keeps some local snapshots https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015